# Active Directory theme policies

Tags: active-directory, terminal-server

I'm currently managing a terminal server in a domain. As the TS-service just got installed, previous users (I logged in with every user once to test it and set up a few things) use the default windows 2008 theme. New users automatically use the fancy Aero theme.

Is there a way to push the Aero theme to all current users?

I currently have something like this in my policies:

[image: policies]

However, when logging in with a user, the theme is not changed. Only if I disable "prohibit access to the control panel", the theme can be changed (doesn't seem to change automatically). But this gives them access to every other control panel feature as well.

And giving users only access to "desk.cpl" CP-applet, gives them an access error as well when attempting to change the theme.

Another question: can I, as admin, take over and/or log in as another user when that user is not logged in?

Thanks

Comment: Enable "Force a specific visual style file or force Windows Clasic" => %windir%\resources\themes\aero\aero.msstyles fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "Force a specific visual style file or force Windows Clasic" => %windir%\resources\themes\aero\aero.msstyles fixed the issue.